# Split a column into multiple columns / cleaning data set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have initialized a table from a pdf into a pandas Dataframe, it looks like the following:

```py
df_current= pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['NaN','NaN','Nan','NaN','Denmark', 'Sweden',
                            'Germany'],
                 'Explained Part':['Personal and job characteristics',
                'Education Occupation Job Employment', 'experience contract',
'Employment contract','20 -7 2 0','4 6 2 0', '-9 -6 -1 :']})
```

The expected (or the output I aim for in the end):

```py
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Denmark', 'Sweden',
'Germany'],'Personal and job characteristics':[20 ,4,-9],
'Education Occupation Job Employment':[-7,6,-6],
'experience contract':[2,2,-1],'Employment contract':[0,0,':']})
```

the problem is: the column 'Explained part' holds 4 columns' worth of data, and some of the data is shown as symbols, like ':'.

I was thinking about using

```
     df[['Personal and job characteristics',
'Education Occupation Job Employment',
'experience contract',
'experience contract']] = df['Explained part'].str.split(" ",expand=True,)
```

But I cannot get it to work.

I want to split the column into 3 but since some cells have split the numbers. 
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance ~
PS. i have updated the question as I think my first post was too hard to understand, I have now added some of the data from the actual problem, and added an expected output, thx for the feedback so far!.

Comment: What is your expected output...? how to do want to handle the rows that split into 4?

Comment: `but since some cells have split the numbers`, okay, so what logic should be applied in those cases?

Comment: You can limit the number of columns that it will be splited by using the **n** parameter:

    `df.Age.str.split(" ",expand=True, n=2)`

But I really don't know if it will helps you and even if it makes any sense because the negative number.

Comment: Hi @ChrisA  I have added the output which I aim for :) Thank you for your comments

Comment: Hej @yatu I have added the output I aim for ( and also added a snippet of the actual problem ) Hopefully this shows what logic i want to apply ( 1 column split into 4, and  the original column deleted) . Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `NaN`s are missing values first remove rows with them by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and then apply your solution with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
df_current= pd.DataFrame({'Country': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Denmark', 'Sweden',
                            'Germany'],
                 'Explained Part':['Personal and job characteristics',
                'Education Occupation Job Employment', 'experience contract',
'Employment contract','20 -7 2 0','4 6 2 0', '-9 -6 -1 :']})
print (df_current)
   Country                       Explained Part
0      NaN     Personal and job characteristics
1      NaN  Education Occupation Job Employment
2      NaN                  experience contract
3      NaN                  Employment contract
4  Denmark                            20 -7 2 0
5   Sweden                              4 6 2 0
6  Germany                           -9 -6 -1 :
```

---

```
df = df_current.dropna(subset=['Country']).copy()
cols = ['Personal and job characteristics','Education Occupation Job Employment',
        'experience contract','Employment contract']
df[cols] = df.pop('Explained Part').str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
   Country Personal and job characteristics  \
4  Denmark                               20   
5   Sweden                                4   
6  Germany                               -9   

  Education Occupation Job Employment experience contract Employment contract  
4                                  -7                   2                   0  
5                                   6                   2                   0  
6                                  -6                  -1                   :
```

Or without `pop`:

```
df = df_current.dropna(subset=['Country']).copy()
cols = ['Personal and job characteristics','Education Occupation Job Employment',
        'experience contract','Employment contract']
df[cols] = df['Explained Part'].str.split(expand=True)
df = df.drop('Explained Part', axis=1)
```